# Does CC'ing in Marketing Cloud affect open rates?

Tags: marketing-cloud

In the situation where I send an email to Subscriber A, and BCC Subscriber B, will each instance of an open by either subscriber be logged in the _Sent data view? Or will only opens by the main recipient be logged?

Comment: Just wondering if you ever got answers on this @Daniel?